# Is it possible to change the Finder sidebar icons

Tags: folders, icon

I know you can change the icons of files, folders, etc, but in the sidebar folders appear the same. Is it possible to give them a custom icon for the sidebar like the Music, Photo's, Movies, etc folders have?

Comment: Would a program like CandyBar suit your needs? http://www.panic.com/candybar/

Comment: It does not state if it can change them in the sidebar. Can anyone vouch for that functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) should do the trick for you.

Comment: I'll have to check it out!

Comment: I downloaded a trial of candy bar from macupdate. It did not change the sidebar icons to color.

Comment: Hmmm...it should. I don't exactly know. It may be that the trial doesn't let you do that.

Comment: They have released a serial code to use it for free  now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the default Mavericks OS X Finder Icons, go to `System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle (right-click > Show Package contents)/Contents/Resources`.

1. `Get Info` on the folder in finder sidebar.
2. Drag the .icns file (e.g. `ToolbarDownloadsFolderIcons.icns` on to the small icon in `Get Info` window to the left of Downloads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on El Capitan I think you have to disable SIP first:

1.Restart your Mac.

2.Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.

3.From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.

4.At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: `csrutil disable`

5.Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.

6.From the  menu, select Restart.