# How to reset default sidebar favourites icons in Finder?

Tags: finder, macos, permission, icon

I broke my Mac Mini, trying set some permissions on some folders for web-development, but somehow ended up removing permissions from everything.

I managed to restore permissions, but have had a few issues since, namely the folder icons on the sidebar in Finder are not reflecting the icons they should be.

The desktop also seems slow to refresh when saving a file to it. They don't appear until I do another action.

Is this something I can fix in Terminal or elsewhere to restore everything back to how it was? Will I have to resort to reinstalling Mavericks?

Alternatively, will restoring from my Time Machine have an impact on things like these folder icons.

[image: Default favorites icons]

edit:

folder permissions when running ls -le as per answer below

```
 drwxrwxrwx@ 16 username  staff    544  5 Nov 21:33 Github
 -rw-r--r--@  1 username  staff      0  4 Nov 02:01 Icon?
 drwxr-xr-x@ 72 username  staff   2448  4 Nov 01:55 Library
 drwx---r-x@ 20 username  staff    680  4 Nov 01:44 Movies
 drwx---rw-@  9 username  staff    306  4 Nov 01:54 Music
 drwx---rw-@  8 username  staff    272  4 Nov 01:45 Pictures
```

etc..

Comment: furthermore: I've created a new admin user, it also has the same issue.

Comment: this kept cropping up now and again for some reason. latest update to OSX fixed it.

Comment: I still think this bug is bizarre.  Took me three months on and off to fix it on my mac.

Answer (score 1):

How did you restore permissions? Manually, or did you use the "Repair" feature in Disk Utilities?

Restoring from a Time Machine backup from before things went bad should work.

One thing you might try before restoring is to delete the Finder preferences. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` then relaunch the Finder (Hold <kbd>Option</kbd> while selecting the Finder icon in the dock). The preference file will be regenerated with the system defaults.

Comment: I used the repair feature. this might be an issue, I don't have the  com.apple.finder.plist file.

Comment: If you don't have a com.apple.finder.plist preference file, then things are certainly "not good" what did you do to your permissions?

Comment: basically it looks like i removed my rights to access every folder/file under Home downwards.

Comment: being and idiot, found the file. deleted it. restarted finder. no change.

Comment: From the terminal could you let me know what you get when you type `ls -le` This should reveal ACLs which could be messed up or missing. One final trick, try dragging one of the folders directly to the sidebar, see what that does.

Comment: answered question in my answer above.

Comment: dragging folder to bar replaces the existing folder with the same. no icon change. removing folder before adding folder back in makes no difference either

Answer (score 1):

You probably restored your preferences (not permissions) by deleting `com.apple.finder.plist`, right? You'll also want to take out one more file, which handles the sidebar, then reboot:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`

It probably wouldn't hurt to Verify Permissions via Disk Utility either (since you mentioned them).

Comment: tried this, but made difference. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

reinstalled mavericks over the top and has cleared everything up.

having deleted the plist files in the other answers beforehand.

thanks

Comment: actually after later restarts and updates, problem has reappeared.

Comment: I had the same problem as you and it was because I had ACL's on my files in `/home`.  If you have that problem  (`0: group:everyone deny write`) go http://backdrift.org/fixing-mac-osx-file-permissions-and-acls-from-the-command-line.

Comment: you should put this as an answer @danger14 so i can upvote it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and it was because I had ACL's on my files in /home. If you have that problem `(0: group:everyone deny write)`

More info at http://backdrift.org/fixing-mac-osx-file-permissions-and-acls-from-the-command-line

If permissions is not your issue, I've discovered an alternate solution which I posted here.
[Is it possible to change the Finder sidebar icons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-it-possible-to-change-the-finder-sidebar-icons)

Comment: `/home/`? That's a bit odd for a Mac, would have expected it to be `/Users/`.