# Finder sidebar icons showing as circles for disks

Tags: macos, finder, icon, sidebar

My Finder looks like this - the icons for local and external volumes are shown correctly in column view, on *Get Info* and on the desktop but in sidebar *Locations* all (except for boot volume) are all just plain circles:

[image: Screenshot]

I checked this question [Changing the Finder icon for an external disk formatted as ExFat?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237337/changing-the-finder-icon-for-an-external-disk-formatted-as-exfat) and none of the volumes have a `.VolumeIcon.icns` file and I have renamed the volumes with no effect.

This question [Change Mac OS X Finder sidebar icons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76897/change-mac-os-x-finder-sidebar-icons) suggested looking at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` but this doesn't seem to exist in Mojave.

This question [How to reset default sidebar favourites icons in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108311/115093) suggested deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` and restarting Finder.  Sure enough this works and the sidebar icons are corrected but after a reboot they are back to being circles.

I am running Mojave 10.14.6 on a mid 2014 MBP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have WhatsYourSign (program that checks if an app is signed) installed by any chance? I removed that and the icons are back to normal

Comment: I did indeed have [What's Your Sign?](https://www.objective-see.com/products/whatsyoursign.html) installed and removing it fixed the icons..

Comment: I suspect this is related to dark mode, and is fixed in more recent versions of What's Your Sign (either 1.6.0 or 1.6.1).

Answer (score 1):

"...*looking at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` but this doesn't seem to exist in Mojave*"

In my Mojave this plist exists!

Did you already "reset" the Finder?:

- click the little apple icon on the top menu bar
- select "ForceQuit"
- select Finder in the list that pops up
- click ForceQuit.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might also be related to Finder Extensions.

It was solved for me in macOS Big Sur 11.1 by going to System Preferences → Extensions → Finder Extensions and disabling Finder Extensions. Then relaunch the Finder:

1. press and hold the Alt/Option key
2. right-click the Finder icon in the Dock
3. select Relaunch

This made the Finder sidebar icons show up as external disks again.